# An ocean of mud?

Tags: planets, chemistry

*The Transgalactic Guide to Solar System M-17* by Jeff Rovin features, among others, the planet Morana, which is described as having oceans of "mud". Obviously, this cannot be normal mud such as we would find on Earth, for a few reasons:

1. It never settles out, and is described as "viscous", yet has a large enough fluid component to have global currents.
2. It is denser than water, but not denser than humans (or at least, not denser than humans in spacesuits), who will still sink in it despite feeling buoyant.
3. While visibility is low, it is apparently *not* zero--you can at least see through it far enough to make a submersible tour of the ruins of a sunken city worthwhile.

Is there any substance that would fit this (extremely vague) bill, which could potentially be available in ocean-forming quantities on an alien world?

Comment: denser than water, but not denser than humans? humans are less dense than water. And if it's denser than humans in spacesuit, those humans would not sink into it

Comment: @L.Dutch I dunno about you, but I sink in water... especially when wearing clothing.

Comment: mud is neither solution nor colloid but suspension which means the particulate will eventually settles to the bottom over time and the water evaporates away, but solution is also out because it isn't cloudy which leaves colloid... such as muddy water and there's a definitive difference between mud and muddy water ;D

Comment: @L.Dutch "humans are less dense than water." marginally less dense and only when alive. Fill their lungs with water and they'll sink (to reemerge as decomposing bodies, puffed up with decomposition gases. Once those are gone, they'll sink again)

Comment: +1 for the mention of a classic travel guide!

Comment: @L.Dutch: Depends on one's BMI, since fatty tissue is less dense than muscle & bone.  Also depends on the lungs: if I take a deep breath, I can float, but if I exhale, I sink.

Answer (score 5):

[Slush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slush) a mixture of solid and liquid of the same substance - behaves mostly as a non-newtonian fluid. Pick your liquids, you can even get water if you have forces that churn the mixture and prevent it from settling with ice on top and water at the bottom. Other liquids will have less of a density segregation, so you may get that in volume without churning - e.g. [Titan-style cryovolcanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)#Cryovolcanism_and_mountains) maintaining a suspension of heavier frozen hydrocarbons in liquid methane.

[Algal blooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algal_bloom) - will modify the viscosity of the water even on Earth by their sheer numbers - bonus point if they excrete [mucilage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucilage) or decay into one when they die. If you have a planet with many active volcanic vents and a biology tuned accordingly, you don't even need light to explain why the life continues in spite of the water become murky and in spite of a low level penetration of light (as an energy source for life to maintain itself and prosper against increasing entropy).